# how to create instagram api exchanger graph php 2021

Tags: instagram

please i have module social media exchange website for ex, instagram
i want to Amending this old code to suit the new update in Instagram to properly reach the user in Instagram to and from the site with automatic redirection from the site to Instagram and vice versa because when writing any username on the site it is clear to me that there is no username with this name in Instagram and this is Old code:

```
<?php
if(! defined('BASEPATH') ){ exit('Unable to view file.'); }
$url = $db->EscapeString($_POST['url']);

if(empty($url)){
    $errMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$lang['b_25'].'</div>';
}else{
    $get = strip_tags(get_data('https://www.instagram.com/'.$url.'/'));
    preg_match('/window._sharedData = (.*?)};/i', $get, $match);
    $json = json_decode($match[1].'}', true);

    if($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['is_private']){
        $errMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$lang['inst_01'].'</div>';
    }elseif(empty($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['id'])){
        $errMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$lang['inst_03'].'</div>';
    }else{
        if($db->QueryGetNumRows("SELECT id FROM `instagram` WHERE `inst_id`='".$db->EscapeString($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['id'])."' LIMIT 1") > 0){
            $errMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'.$lang['inst_02'].'</div>';
        }else{
            $db->Query("INSERT INTO `instagram` (user, inst_id, url, title, p_av, max_clicks, daily_clicks, cpc, country, sex) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$db->EscapeString($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['id'])."', '".$db->EscapeString($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['username'])."', '".$db->EscapeString($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['full_name'])."', '".$db->EscapeString($json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url'])."', '".$max_clicks."', '".$daily_clicks."', '".$cpc."', '".$country."', '".$gender."') ");
            $errMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'.$lang['inst_04'].'</div>';
            $error = 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Up please......

Comment: Please up this.